# How to fix incompatible pointer types when using a function to fill a two dimensional array

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to write a function for filling a two dimensional array of size undefined in the function call but vsc is complaining that pointer types are incompatible

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ROW1 20
#define ROWNUM1 20
#define ROW2 20
#define ROWNUM2 20

int max( int x, int y){

    if(x > y) return x;
    else return y;
}

int getMatrix(int (*matrix)[]){
    return 1; //don't mind this, a placeholder
}

int main(){
    int matrix1[ROWNUM1][ROW1], matrix2[ROWNUM2][ROW2];
    int rowLen1, rowLen2;

    printf("%d", getMatrix(matrix1));
    rowLen2 = getMatrix(matrix2);

    return 0;
}
```

I get this in the vsc problems tab but the code runs without comlaint
"passing argument 1 of 'getMatrix' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]". Thanks for any and all advice on fixing this in advance

Comment: Try adding `printf("%d\n", matrix[2][3]);` to the `getMatrix` function, and see what the compiler has to say about that.

Comment: @user3386109: That is not the cause of the problem asked about, and it is also not a barrier to filling in the function with working code. For example, replacing the stub OP provided for this question (as is proper for a [mre]) with code beginning with `int (*NewPointer)[DefinedSize] = matrix;` would provide a usable pointer.

Comment: @Someone Someone Using different values for the defines would make the question more illustrative.

Comment: The obvious fix in this case would be `int getMatrix(int matrix[ROWNUM1][ROW1])`. Maybe one day MSVC will update the compiler to year 1989 standards or later, but in the meantime you can use this fix.

Answer (score 4):

This is a defect in MSVC. MSVC is not a conforming C compiler.

`int (*matrix)[]` declares `matrix` to be a pointer to an array of an unknown number of `int`. I suspect MSVC may be handling it internally as an array of zero elements.

In `getMatrix(matrix1)`, the array `matrix1` is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element, so the argument to the function is a pointer to an array of `ROW1` `int` (20 `int`).

According to the C standard, a pointer to an array of an unknown number of `int` and a pointer to an array of `ROW1` `int` are compatible types, so the compiler should accept this. Per C 2018 6.7.6.1 2, two pointer types are compatible if they are identically qualified and point to compatible types. Per 6.7.6.2 6, two array types are compatible if they have the same size if both have their sizes specified, but there is no requirement if one or both does not have its size specified. The array types are then compatible merely if their element types are compatible.

If MSVC’s diagnostic is merely a warning, that is not itself non-compliance with the C standard, as the standard allows compilers to issue warnings beyond what the standard requires. However, asserting the pointer types are incompatible is false.

Above, I noted I suspect MSVC may be treating the parameter as a pointer to an array of zero elements. This is because testing with MSVC 19.37 yields a different warning message that mentions `int (*)[0]` as the type. You may be using a different version of MSVC that has a different message but also treats the size as zero, and this would explain the message about incompatible types, as an array of zero elements would not be compatible with an array of 20 elements (notwithstanding the fact that an array of zero elements is another conflict with the C standard).

Testing seems to show MSVC 19.37 (the latest on Compiler Explorer) does not support variable-length arrays, even with `/std:c17`, so your options for working around this may be limited. You could declare the parameter as `void *`, then assign it to an `int *p` and do the address calculations yourself, as with `p[row * RowLength + column]`. (That has additional pedantic complications with the C standard, but I expect it to work in MSVC.)

Comment: so it's no big deal and just msvc whining about things that are not an issue to a compiler that conforms to rules of the C standard?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the suggestions by Eric, you could template the function and take a fixed-length array.

```
template<int cols, int rows>
int getMatrix(int matrix[cols][rows]){
    return 1; //don't mind this, a placeholder
}
```

or

```
template<int rows>
int getMatrix(int *matrix[rows]){
    return 1; //don't mind this, a placeholder
}
```

If the compiler can't deduce the template parameters, add them explicitly eg `getMatrix<ROWNUM2, ROW2>(matrix2)`.